# Accessing Bytes in BinaryJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have implemented a NodeJs server, using [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/). At this moment, I can stream audio from several clients and store as wav file in the server. This is the server code of how I am doing it:

```
  binaryServer.on('connection', function (client) {
  var fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter('records/' + n + '.wav', {
    channels: 1,
    sampleRate: 48000,
    bitDepth: 16
  });

  client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {
    stream.pipe(fileWriter);

      stream.on('end', function () {

          fileWriter.end();
    });

  });
});
```

Now, I want to go further. I want to store the streams in memory, to use in my advantage. To do that, I need to be able to access the bytes of stream (right?). How can I achieve this? I found nothing in BinaryJS API. It seems that I need to implement a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

**console.log(stream):**

```
  { domain: null,
  _events:
   { close: [ [Function], [Function: onclose], [Function: cleanup] ],
     data: [Function: ondata],
     end: [ [Function: onend], [Function: cleanup] ],
     error: [Function: onerror] },
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  id: 0,
  _socket:
   { _socket:
      { _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 530,
        _bytesDispatched: 129,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleStart: 20175228,
        parser: null,
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     bytesReceived: 10,
     readyState: 1,
     supports: { binary: true },
     protocol: undefined,
     protocolVersion: 13,
     upgradeReq:
      { _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        _pendings: [],
        _pendingIndex: 0,
        upgrade: true,
        url: '/',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        statusMessage: null,
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: false,
        _dumped: false,
        parser: null },
     _isServer: true,
     _receiver:
      { fragmentedBufferPool: [Object],
        unfragmentedBufferPool: [Object],
        state: [Object],
        overflow: [],
        headerBuffer: <Buffer 45 28 26 9b e8 9c ff 02 8e 91>,
        expectOffset: 0,
        expectBuffer: <Buffer 45 28>,
        expectHandler: [Function],
        currentMessage: [],
        dead: false,
        onerror: [Function],
        ontext: [Function],
        onbinary: [Function],
        onclose: [Function],
        onping: [Function],
        onpong: [Function] },
     _sender: { _socket: [Object], firstFragment: true, _events: [Object] },
     _events:
      { close: [Object],
        open: [Function],
        drain: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        message: [Object] },
     binaryType: 'arraybuffer' },
  writable: true,
  readable: true,
  paused: false,
  _closed: false,
  _ended: false }
```

Comment: It seems the `data` events emitted by the stream have `Buffer`s as their payload. Can't you just use those?

Comment: I found two types of buffer. But unfortunately, and I don't know why, is always empty. Only headers have some information.

Comment: Should I use 'data' event?

Comment: Yes, you should, if you can get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
binaryServer.on('connection', function (client) {

  var fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter('records/' + n + '.wav', {
    channels: 1,
    sampleRate: 48000,
    bitDepth: 16
  });

  //Evento --> quando se inicia o stream 
  client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {

    stream.pipe(fileWriter);
    /****the solution*****/
    stream.on('data', function(data){
      console.log(data);//<---Buffer type
    })   
    /**********************/ 
      stream.on('end', function () {

          console.log("end stream");
          fileWriter.end();
    });

  });
});
```

Thanks for your tip @Bergi. It makes me think in a different way..